# error in setting the value of semaphore

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore

I have write the following few lines of code , which is configure the semaphore in C language under Linux OS :

```
    int semid = semget(1234 , 1 , IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(semid < 0)
        printf("ERROR in semget \n ");
        if( semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, 1) < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR in setting value of semaphore \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

but the problem is , my program always show the message : `ERROR in semget 
ERROR in setting value of semaphore` , and i dont know why ?

Comment: Check the return value from semget.

Comment: @DrC , the problem seems that in 'semget`.

Comment: Your revised code needs fixing as it calls semctl in the error case.

Comment: First of all, you can't semctl if semget failed and here, if semid < 0,  it failed. May be you key is invalid, try to make a good one with key = ftok(argv[0], ID_PROJET);